# How to insert a new picture beside existing one without also making it black and white?

Tags: photoshop, black-and-white

I have picture in my project. I made it black and white. Now I want to insert a new picture, but every time I insert one, it becomes black and white too. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using Photoshop without any clear explanation as to how it's relevant to photography.

Comment: @PhilipKendall where should I ask about Photoshop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making your first picture black&white (1 bit per pixel, or 8 bpp grays...) promote it back to RGB (24 bpp) or whatever mode is the inserted picture.
This way the inserted picture won't be be turned to B&W.